# Writing a program that can handle a Heap that has K amount of children

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, binary-heap

I have researched binary Heaps and I am still very confused about what to do for this program If I could get some guidance I would really appreciate it I'm still learning java and having a lot of trouble doing so.

A k-ary heap is like a binary heap (where k = 2), but (with one possible
exception) non-leaf nodes have k children instead of 2 children. Implement k-ary heap
as a min-priority queue for an arbitrary k ≥ 2 to support following operations:

• insert (x): inserts the element x to the heap.

• extract-min(): removes and returns the element of heap with the smallest key.

k-ary heap is to be implemented using an array of predeﬁned size. Also study the
relative eﬃciencies of the data structure for varying values of k, by measuring the time
required for performing sequence of operations given the input ﬁle for k = 2, 4, 6, 8,
10. In the input ﬁle “IN” stands for insert and “EX” stand for extract-min operation.

Answer (score 3):

A binary heap is implemented as an [almost full (=complete)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) binary tree. For your k-ary heap, you will probably need to generate `almost full k-ary tree` [all levels in the tree are full, except the last one, inwhich you fill the tree from left to right] , and repeat the same ops the original heap do, but with more then 2 children per node.

With some knowledge on [heap ops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), especially the `heapify`, and the tip above, it shouldn't be too hard to implement your k-ary heap.

To implement it as an array, simply follow how a [binary tree is implemented as an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation), and follow these ideas when you implement your complete k-ary tree as an array.